# Halt the processing of DragDrop events on displaying a window while performing drag & drop between grids

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have started working on it since past couple of months.
I have an issue handling drag & drop events.

I have two grids placed side by side and I am performing drag & drop operation from left grid(Grid A) to the right grid(Grid B). I am using both **BeforeDrop** and **Drop** events on *Grid B*. On drag and drop of data from *Grid A* to *Grid B*, I am displaying a custom *Window* having a *combo box* in it.

The displaying of the window and selecting values in combo box using **Select** event is done in the **BeforeDrop** event and reloading the *Grid B's* store is done in the **Drop** event.

The problem is when I drag and drop the data from Grid A to Grid B, the **BeforeDrop** event is triggered where the window pops up and **simultaneously before even selecting the combo box data, the *Drop* event also gets triggered reloading the Grid B's store in the background**.

I want the **Drop** event to be triggered after I select an item in the combo box. Is there a way to halt the triggering process once the window is displayed?

Any Help is much appreciated..

Here is some code:

**Panel with two grids along with drag drop events**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    frame: false,
    height: 708,
    width: 1150,
    layout: {
        type: 'border'
    },
    title: 'MyApp',
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        var GridADragDrop = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop', {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'GridADDGroup',
            dropGroup: ''
        });
        var GridBDragDrop = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop', {
            ptype: 'gridviewdragdrop',
            dragGroup: 'GridADDGroup',
            dropGroup: 'GridADDGroup'
        });
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'gridb',
                title: 'Grid B',
                store: 'GridBStore',
                viewConfig: {
                    id: 'Bview',
                    plugins: [GridBDragDrop],
                    /*Both Events have been used for Grid B*/
                    listeners: {
                        beforedrop: {
                            fn: me.onBeforeDrop,
                            scope: me
                        },
                        drop: {
                            fn: me.onDrop,
                            scope: me
                        }
                    }
                },
                columns: [{
                    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'id',
                    text: 'ID'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    text: 'Name'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'grid',
                id: 'grida',
                title: 'Grid A',
                store: 'GridAStore',
                viewConfig: {
                    id: 'Aview',
                    plugins: [GridADragDrop]
                },
                columns: [{
                    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'id',
                    text: 'ID'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    text: 'Name'
                }]
            }]
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
    onBeforeDrop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropFunction, options) {

        console.log("The before drop event is triggered!!");
        // Creating the window
        var window = Ext.create('MyApp.Window');
        // Getting the combo box object from the window object 
        var combobox = window.items.items[0];
        // Adding 'select' listener to the combo box
        combobox.on('select', function (combo, records, options) {
            // I do some stuff here
            //...   
            // Once finished I destroy window
            window.destroy();
        });
        // Display the window on item drop
        window.show();
    },
    onDrop: function (node, data, overModel, dropPosition, options) {

        console.log("The drop event is triggered!!");

        var GridB = Ext.getCmp('gridb'); // Grid B
        var GridBStore = GridB.getStore(); // Grid B store

        //Reload the GridB store once the item has been dropped
        GridBStore.reload();
    }
});
```

**My custom Window:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Window', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    height: 82,
    hidden: false,
    id: 'droptaskwindow',
    width: 171,
    layout: {
        type: 'absolute'
    },
    title: 'Create Task',
    modal: true,
    expandOnShow: false,
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                x: 10,
                y: 10,
                id: 'combodroptask',
                width: 130,
                fieldLabel: 'ID',
                labelPad: 1,
                labelWidth: 45,
                allowBlank: false,
                editable: false,
                displayField: 'Name',
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },
});
```

As soon as I drag and drop, I get the window but in the console i see that both events have been executed:

The before drop event is triggered!!
The drop event is triggered!!

**NOTE:**
One thing I noticed that on displaying simple alert message, only the BEFORE event is triggered but not the DROP event unless I click on OK. This is just the way I want it to work when my window is displayed.

Alert Msg works:

```
onBeforeDrop: function(node, data, overModel, dropPosition, dropFunction, options) {

    console.log("The before drop event is triggered!!");
    alert("Dropping..");// IT WORKS!! It Does not allow DROP event to execute..unless OK is clicked
    Ext.Msg.alert('Status', 'Dropping..'); //This doesn't work..same as my window

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alert windows pause the execution of the javascript thread, while Ext windows do not. That explains the different behaviors you've observed.

To perform asynchronous operation in the `beforedrop` event, you must use the `dropHandlers` (see the [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.DragDrop-event-beforedrop)). Note that `dropHandlers` in Ext4.2 is documented as `dropFunction` in Ext4.1, but from what I've seen in the code, the doc for 4.1 is wrong and things work as described in the 4.2 doc.

So, in your `beforedrop` handler, you should add (with your current argument names):

```
dropFunction.wait = true;
```

And, later, when you're done with your window's business (e.g. in the handler of the ok button):

```
dropFunction.processDrop();
```

Comment: Hi rixo, Thanks for the response.It is working just the way I wanted. Thank you so much :)